# Calculating event throughput in splunk

Tags: splunk

I want to find throughput for target events. I identify my target events by EVENT_PROCESSED. So my query is:

```
index=myIndex namespace=myNamespace host=myHost log=\*EVENT_PROCESSED* | bucket _time span=1h | chart count(EVENT_PROCESSED)/3600 as throughput by _time
```

But it doesn't work. Error is:

```
Error in 'chart' command: The data field 'count(EVENT_PROCESSED)/3600' is malformed.
```

What mistake am I making here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `timechart`:

```
index=myIndex namespace=myNamespace host=myHost log=\*EVENT_PROCESSED*
| timechart span=1h count(log) as count
```

###edit - change to field *name* (log) from field *value*